# Loading vector with bit matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I have a code segment here that loads zeroes into a vector that represents a bit matrix. When the program runs and tries to write the result in a output file I get a seg fault. The program runs fine when it does not write in the output file.

```
[code]
Bitmatrix::Bitmatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    int count = 0;                                                                          // count variable
    int count2 = 0;                                                                        // 2nd count variable

    if( rows <= 0 || cols <= 0 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Value of rows or columns is less than or equal to zero\n" );  // print error message
        M.resize( 1 );                                                                 // resize to 1 x 1 matrix
        M[0] = '0';                                                                   // set 0 as the value
    }
    else
        M.resize( rows );                                                           // resize matrix to number of rows
        for( count = 0; count < M.size(); count++ )
        {
            for( count2 = 0; count2 < cols; count2++ )
            {
                M[count].push_back( '0' );                                       // fill matrix with zeros  
            }
        }
}[/code]
```

The function that prints in the output file is:

```
[code]void Bitmatrix::Write(string fn)
{
    ofstream out;                                                      // output stream object
    int count = 0;                                                    // count variable
    int count2 = 0;                                                  // 2nd count variable

    out.open( fn.c_str() );                                        // open output file
    for( count = 0; count < M.size(); count++ )
    {
        for( count2 = 0; count2 < M[count].size(); count++ )
        {
            out << M[count][count2];
        }
        out << endl;
    }
}[/code]
```

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

In your function `Write()` in the second for loop you are incrementing `count` instead of `count2`:

```
for( count2 = 0; count2 < M[count].size(); count++ <= should be count2
```

The next line then invokes the segmentation fault, because you are accessing a value in the matrix that is out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks. I always overlook something like that.